# Problem by using JSON in a PHP script with Unity

Tags: c#, php, json, unity-game-engine

I try to work inside Unity scripts with JSON datas from a SQL table. I'm using PHP to communicate with Unity.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
try
{

    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx.mysql.db;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');

}
catch(Exception $e)
{

        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());

}
$Wallet_Number = $_GET['Wallet_Number'];

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT Wallet_Number, NFT, Montant_Mise, Date_Spin FROM Wallets_Bets WHERE Wallet_Number = ?');

$req->execute(array($_GET['Wallet_Number']));
$req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json['Wallet_Number'] = $req->fetchAll();
$json['content'] = count($json['Wallet_Number']);

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

The script is working fine, here is a result from a request:

```
{"Wallet_Number":[{"Wallet_Number":"XXX","NFT":"RetourFutur","Montant_Mise":"0","Date_Spin":"06\/04\/2022"},{"Wallet_Number":"XXX","NFT":"RetourFutur","Montant_Mise":"0","Date_Spin":"06\/04\/2022"},{"Wallet_Number":"XXX","NFT":"RetourFutur","Montant_Mise":"0,010000","Date_Spin":"06\/04\/2022"},{"Wallet_Number":"XXX","NFT":"RetourFutur","Montant_Mise":"0,01","Date_Spin":"06\/04\/2022"},{"Wallet_Number":"XXX","NFT":"MenInBlack","Montant_Mise":"0,01","Date_Spin":"06\/04\/2022"},{"Wallet_Number":"XXX","NFT":"Shinning","Montant_Mise":"0,10","Date_Spin":"06\/04\/2022"}],"content":6}
```

Here is my Unity class to manage de datas:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[System.Serializable]
public class OVHJsonObject
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
  
    
        public string Wallet_Number;
        public string NFT;
        public string Montant_Mise;
        public string Date_Spin;

}
```

And finaly the Unity script which manage the JSON datas:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SimpleJSON;

namespace AllArt.Solana.Example
{
public class NGetJSONData : MonoBehaviour
{


    string queryURL = "https://xxx.fr/CheckWallet.php?Wallet_Number=";
    
    public static string NPKey;
    public string NValue;
    public static OVHJsonObject[ ] Wallet_data = new OVHJsonObject[9] ;

            void Start()
    {
        
        
    }

        public void PopulateList() {

        NPKey = SimpleWallet.instance.wallet.GetAccount(0).GetPublicKey;
        Debug.Log (" NPKEY : " + NPKey);
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(queryURL + NPKey));   

    }

        IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
            int page = pages.Length - 1;
            

            switch (webRequest.result)
            {
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                    Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                    Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                    Debug.Log(pages[page] + ":\nReceived: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    NValue = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;                    
                    Wallet_data[0] = JsonUtility.FromJson<OVHJsonObject>(NValue);
                        Debug.Log(" Wallet Name : "+ Wallet_data[0] .Wallet_Number);
                
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
       

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

}
}
}
```

When running, I get no error from Unity but the fowllowing line always send an empty value (no null but nothing inside)

```
Debug.Log(" Wallet Name : "+ Wallet_data[0] .Wallet_Number);
```

Do you know what I am missing ? It seems the JSON format from my PHP script is not recognize in my Unity script.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Type and json data you give to JsonUtility.FromJson (type, variable) are not compatible.
You have Wallet_Number and int in Json. Then you first have parse Wallet_Number and then reach other elements in Wallet_Number.
When I test with your json data this code worked:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class WalletData
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public string Wallet_Number;
    public string NFT;
    public string Montant_Mise;
    public string Date_Spin;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class WalletsData
{
    public WalletData[] Wallet_Number;
    public int content;
}
WalletsData wallets = JsonUtility.FromJson<WalletsData>(jsonData);
Debug.Log(wallets.Wallet_Number[0].Wallet_Number);
```